# How do you troubleshoot Family Safety reports

Tags: windows-8, troubleshooting, parental-controls

I have set up Microsoft Family Safety in Windows 8 for my daughter's account.

At first I got meaningful reports via e-mail each week. But then the e-mails started reporting no activity, even though my daughter still uses the computer. The e-mails are still sent to me, but indicate that she is not using the computer at all.

Family Safety is definitely still active on the computer. It limits how long she can use the computer. So only the e-mail reports are buggy.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this since the e-mails are generated by Microsoft. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure she's not pulling wool over your eyes and booting another OS? :)

Comment: She is quite computer savvy for her age, actually, but she is nine, so no, she is not booting another OS :)

Comment: If you go and look at the reports directly on the Family Safety website, does it show activity, etc.?  Is her Windows account still properly associated to the right "Family Safety Member"?

Comment: She has access to two different computers with her account. The website shows activity for the other computer, but not for the one I am talking about here. Both computers are listed under associated computers. But there is a note about Family Safety not getting any report from that computer for a while. However, I still don't know why there has been no report from the computer. On the computer itself her user is listed as being under Family Safety.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is logon as your daughter and see if you get any activity.  If you do, could your daughter be logging on using another account?  Including yours!

On another tack, someone appropriate could gently question her best friend.

My theory is that if the email system was buggy, you would see lots more reports over the internet about this problem.